# Can I rely on OSVERSIONINFO.szCSDVersion or Environment.OSVersion.ServicePack to always be of the form "Service Pack X"?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, operating-system, servicepacks

The title basically says it all. I need to determine the Windows Service Pack number (in numeric form), and [Environment.OSVersion.ServicePack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.servicepack.aspx) (which basically just returns [OSVERSIONINFO.szCSDVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834.aspx)) just returns a string.

In all my tests, this string turned out to be in the form `""` (no service pack) or `"Service Pack X"`, with `X` being a number. So the algorithm to parse this should be quite simple.

My question: **Can I rely on this string to always have this format?**

(One part of me says no, beause it's not documented. The other part says yes, because surely a lot of existing code would break if MS would decide to return, say, `"SP 2 (x86)"` for Windows 7 SP2. Thus, they won't do it. Does anyone have more information on that?)

Comment: It isn't documented.  Pinvoke GetVersionEx() to get the wServicePackMajor/Minor numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No you can't](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/542106-The-Service-Pack-string/), some versions use translated strings! If you look at the strings from the image in that link you see that you might get away with just using the first number you find in the string.

OSVERSIONINFOEX was added in NT4 SP6, if you call GetVersionEx you only need to deal with the string on Win9x and < NT4 SP6 and use OSVERSIONINFOEX.wServicePackMajor on other systems.

Comment: ...and IIRC on Win9x the string uses letters like "B" and "C" and not numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `BuildLabEx` instead. It has a specified format which has held since early builds of Windows. Not sure if you can find it in WMI (you should be able to), but it's in the registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\BuildLabEx`

Example:

`7601.17640.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.110632-1508`

If it makes you feel more comfortable, you could rely initially on `CSDVersion` matching a certain regex for simplicity, and fail back onto `BuildLabEx` if it doesn't match.

Comment: Using some random undocumented registry value is better? On XP this is called BuildLab and not BuildLabEx!

Comment: Actually, BuildLab and BuildLabEx exist side by side, with older operating systems not supplying the extended version. If you had fully read my response, you would have seen that I didn't say he should use the registry value, but rather look for it in the WMI, which *is* a documented mechanism for fetching such data.

Comment: As I said, wasn't sure where it's stored in WMI.